# BTRFS: Cannot mount: errno=-28 No space left (after replace/balance)

Tags: btrfs

After I successfully replaced the smaller disk of a RAID1 pool with a larger one, I cannot mount filesystems from the pool anymore (only with `-o ro`).

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt
```

It mounts *read-only* and `dmesg | grep BTRFS` shows:

```
BTRFS info (device sda): disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS info (device sda): has skinny extents
BTRFS info (device sda): checking UUID tree
BTRFS info (device sda): balance: resume -dusage=90 -musage=90 -susage=90
BTRFS info (device sda): relocating block group 170456317952 flags system|raid1
BTRFS info (device sda): relocating block group 1104150528 flags data|raid1
BTRFS info (device sda): found 1 extents
BTRFS info (device sda): relocating block group 30408704 flags metadata|raid1
BTRFS: Transaction aborted (error -28)
BTRFS: error (device sda) in __btrfs_free_extent:3106: errno=-28 No space left
BTRFS info (device sda): forced readonly
BTRFS: error (device sda) in btrfs_run_delayed_refs:2209: errno=-28 No space left
BTRFS info (device sda): 1 enospc errors during balance
BTRFS info (device sda): balance: ended with status: -30
```

The actual disks (sda, sdb) are big enough:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sd{a,b}*
Disk /dev/sda: 232.89 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
[...]
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
[...]

# btrfs fi df /mnt
Data, RAID1: total=147.04GiB, used=147.02GiB
System, RAID1: total=8.00MiB, used=48.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=1.00GiB, used=458.84MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=181.53MiB, used=0.00B
```

**How can I delete subvolumes, resize, balance when I cannot mount the filesystem?**

Comment: My guess is you need to [`skip_balance`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)) to avoid mounting read-only. `umount`, then mount with `skip_balance`. Free some space or resize, or whatever. Then `btrfs balance resume` (or maybe `cancel` first and eventually `start` again). This is not an answer because it's just an **untested** guess.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! I still cannot increase the pool size. `btrfs fi resize` reports "ERROR: unable to resize '/mnt': no enough free space". `btrfs fi df` reports that it's full but `fdisk` reports that there is enough space (see above). Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed: `btrfs fi resize 1:max /mnt; btrfs fi resize 2:max /mnt` worked!

Comment: Nice. Now [you can write an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error occurred because there wasn't enough space for automatic balancing on mount. To skip the automatic balancing, I can mount with

```
mount -o skip_balance /dev/sda /mnt
```

Note the mount option [`skip_balance`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)).

To resize/increase the filesystem size, I had to use

```
btrfs fi resize 1:max /mnt
btrfs fi resize 2:max /mnt
```

where 1 and 2 are the device ids (devid) listed in `btrfs fi show /mnt`, `fi` is short for `filesystem`, and `max` is special keyword for the maximum size. You could also use e.g. `250G` instead of `max`.

Note that `btrfs fi resize max /mnt` did not work for some reason. Maybe because the hard drives have a different capacity.

Thank you, Kamil!